# $k$-means clustering as an operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, machine-learning

Consider a $L^2$ map $f:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ for some compact $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$. Using the $k$-means clustering algorithm, we decompose $\Omega$ into $k$ regions $\Omega_1,\dots,\Omega_k$ for which $f$ is constant within each region. Let $f_j \in \mathbb{R}^s$ be that constant value for each $\Omega_j$. The "clustered" function can be just written as a piecewise uniform function:
\begin{equation}
f^c(x) = \sum_{i=1}^k\chi_{\Omega_i}(x)f_i
\end{equation}
with $\chi$ being the indicator fucntion. I observe that $f^c$ is also $L^2$. I was just wondering what we can say about the operator $\Phi: L^2(\Omega) \to L^2(\Omega)$ given by $f \mapsto f^c$. Is it continuous? Injective?

Also, what about if we let $f$ not be $L^2$ but in the Sobolev space $H^s$? What can we say about the operator $\Phi: H^2(\Omega) \to L^2(\Omega)$ defined in the identical way?

Comment: "Using the $k$-means clustering algorithm, we decompose $\Omega$ into $k$ regions $\Omega_1,\dots,\Omega_k$" this is not clear for me? How can you do that ?

Comment: See this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering. It is an unsupervised algorithm used to partition a domain into "clusters" to drastically reduce computation time. Its just like making a high-res picture lower resolution.

Comment: It is not to partition a domain. It is to partition a set of observations. However $\Omega$ can be any thing (compact)in your question.

Comment: Yes - you are right. I think what I care about is any arbitrary domain decomposition, but where I got $k$-means was by studying this paper: https://zeliangliu.com/publication/liu-2016-self/preprint.pdf. In particular, see section 2.2.1: Domain decomposition via k-means clustering.